# SQL - delete all values in table X that are less than the MIN of table Y

Tags: sql

I am trying to create an sql query that is (loosely) of the form `DELETE FROM X` anything < `MIN FROM Y`. I would want to do:

```
DELETE * FROM S
WHERE s.value < MIN(Y.value)
```

where `S` and `Y` are two different tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current attempt does not appear to be far off.  Try this:

```
DELETE FROM S WHERE S.value < (SELECT MIN(value) FROM Y)
```

You also did not tell us which RDBMS you are using, but the answer to your question should not vary much.